# Martingale Maximal function Inequality

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales

If we have the martingale $\{X_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ where $X_n = \mathbb{E}[X|\mathcal{F}_n]$ for some $X \in L^1$ and filtration $\{\mathcal{F}_j\}$

We have the martingale maximal function defined as: 
$$(MX)(x) = \sup_{n \geq 0} |X_n(x)|$$

If we define $$Z_n = \sup_{0 \leq j \leq n} |X_j(x)|$$

How does one prove the following inequality? $$\mu(\{x: |Z_n(x)| > \alpha\}) \leq \frac{C}{\alpha}||X_n||_{L^1}$$

Answer (score 1):

If $\alpha > 0$, then let 
$$
\tau := \inf \{ k\ge 0 : |X_k| > \alpha \},
$$
so that $\tau \wedge n \le n$ is a bounded stopping time.  Notice that 
$$
\{ x : Z_n(x) > \alpha \} = \{ x : \tau(x) \le n \}.
$$
Since $x\mapsto |x|$ is convex, we know that $|X_k|$ is a submartingale.  The optional stopping theorem implies that
$$
\mathbb{E} |X_{\tau \wedge n}| \le \mathbb{E} |X_n|.
$$
However,
$$
\mathbb{E} |X_{\tau\wedge n}| \ge \alpha \cdot \mu(\{ x: \tau(x) \le n \})
$$
and so,
$$
\mu(\{x : Z_n(x) > \alpha\}) \le \frac{1}{\alpha}\mathbb{E}|X_n| = \frac{1}{\alpha}\|X_n\|_{L^1}.
$$